# Can not start Android emulators on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm getting this error when I try to run the emulators using the command line:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd
> pixel_2_pi e_9_0_-_api_28 Failed to open
> /usr/local/google/home/joshuaduong/emu/master/prebuilts/android-e
> mulator-build/qemu-android-deps/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
> Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational emulator:
> ERROR: It seems too many emulator instances are running on this
> machine. Aborting.

Comment: End other emulator instances from task manager.

Comment: delete all other instance from task manager and retry. I make a `bat` file for automate the launch of emulator : https://github.com/samuel3105/Android-AVD-windows. just download it and launch it

Comment: No Other emualtor instances running

Comment: deleted all other instances no from task manager, I did  also adb kill-server command, no luck same error.

Comment: Make sure that the version of VS is the latest .